# A regularized hypergeometric function related question

Tags: special-functions

I'm interested in finding a way (if possible) of expressing this specific value of the  regularized hypergeometric function in terms of known constants. How might I use *Mathematica* to check
this possibility?
Here is the value

```
Derivative[{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, 0][HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, -1]
```

Comment: I edited your question. Please don't offer that kind of "rewards". Upvote all the answers from all users that you think deserve the upvote instead.

Comment: Or, open a bounty if you feel generous enough.

Comment: @belisarius I don't think there is something wrong with upvoting questions (as a reward). I'm sure the person that can give me the proper answer has many answers that are worth being upvoted.

Comment: Both things are independent. If you want to upvote good Q&A, it's good and go for it. But you have an specific tool for rewarding good answers: a bounty. Also, if you serially upvote 20 answers from the same user, all fraud alarms will be triggered.

Comment: @belisarius is right on all points.  Also see: [Please don't stalker-vote!](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/280/121).  You would not be helping the person you were attempting to reward.

Comment: The point is I think totally different from you. Moreover, I know how to upvote the answers such that they won't be deleted by the system (I won't give them all at once). In the meantime I've changed my mind and I think I'm going to upvote 50 times the user that firstly give me the right answer.

Comment: You'll want to read this stuff too:

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55708/expanding-derivatives-of-hypergeometric-functions?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can expand the hypergeometric function as a series of the last argument and take the derivative

```
series[Derivative[n__][f_][args__], k_] := 
  Module[{vars = {args} /. Except[_List | List] :> Unique[]},
   FullSimplify[# (Last@vars)^k /. 
         Thread[Flatten@vars -> Flatten@{args}], 
        Assumptions -> {k ∈ Integers, k >= 0}] &@
      D[SeriesCoefficient[
        FunctionExpand[f @@ vars], {Last@vars, 0, k}], ##] & @@ 
    Transpose@{Flatten@vars, Flatten@{n}}];

simplify[expr_] := Sum[series[expr, k], {k, 0, ∞}]
```

The series expansion is

```
expr = Derivative[{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, 0][
    HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, -1];
series[expr, k]
```

[image]

However, the summation returns the initial hypergeometric function

```
simplify[expr]
```

[image]

Probably, there is no simple form for this expression. However, this method works for another arguments

```
simplify@Derivative[{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, 0][
   HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, 1]
```

[image]

Of course, this method have certain limitations (e.g. series convergence) but sometimes it gives interesting results that are impossible to get with other methods.

Comment: @Chris's sis Please, do no upvote my other answers! Let other people decide how good is this answer.

Comment: My answer below was aimed at obtaining a closed form solution for the derivative of the HyperGeometricRegularized function that is needed. The answer that was obtained above is given by the first order term in the series expansion f[x_] = FunctionExpand[HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, x}, -1]].

Comment: @JEP It contains the derivative of `HypergeometricPFQ`. Unfortunately there is some mistakes in further expansion. It seems to me that proper expansion can not be summarized...

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly an answer but perhaps it's a step in the right direction. Actually with the subsequent edits I think it is an answer. You'll need to do the calculations yourself and check that I didn't screw anything up but I think this works and gives you a closed form expression.

```
f[x_] = FunctionExpand[HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, x}, -1]]
Series[f[x], {x, 2, 2}]
```

as it gives an answer (i.e. the coefficient of (x-2) ) in terms of HypergeometricPFQ plus other stuff. The documentation has a series expansion for HypergeometricPFQ in terms of these things called Pochhammer symbols which are gamma functions (a)_k = Gamma[1+k]/Gamma[k]=k.
You'll have p=4, a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=1 and q=3 with b_1=b_2=2 and b_3=x and z=1.  That factor in the series with the "a"s is (Gamma[1+k]/Gamma[k])^4 because p=4 and the "a"s are all unity. Then you have to go through the same reasoning with the "b"s remembering that b_3 carries the x dependence. It's pretty messy but it might end up giving something reasonable.

EDIT: I managed to beat this into a closed form solution. The series expansion above gives you:  (-((3 Zeta[3])/4) + 3/4 EulerGamma Zeta[3] + a derivative of HypergeometricPFQ . Use the series expansion of HypergeometricPFQ[{1,1,1,1},{2,2,2+x},1] around x = 0 will give you that derivative. I found -Sum[PolyGamma[0, 2 + k]/(k^2 (1 + k)^2), {k, 1, Infinity}]=1/6 (36 - 18 EulerGamma - [Pi]^2 + 2 EulerGamma [Pi]^2 - 24 Zeta[3])  for the coefficient of x in the series expansion for HypergeometricPFQ[{1,1,1,1},{2,2,2+x},1]. So your answer should be 
(-((3 Zeta[3])/4) + 3/4 EulerGamma Zeta[3] + 1/6 (36 - 18 EulerGamma - [Pi]^2 + 2 EulerGamma [Pi]^2 - 24 Zeta[3]) =

1/12 (72 - 2 [Pi]^2 + EulerGamma (4 [Pi]^2 + 9 (-4 + Zeta[3])) - 57 Zeta[3])

which probably has some mistakes but I don't think there are any insurmountable difficulties in performing the manipulations. Hmmm. The numerical evaluation of the last formula gives:
-0.667003 . The correct numerical answer is -0.338863 so I messed something up but I think if you write it out carefully as you go you can coax Mathematica into giving a closed form symbolic formula.